# Set attribute to type, select is nor working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change 3 text inputs to  selects and append options underneath, but the input stays the same.

Here is my js code

```
let inputSelect=['protons2', 'atomic2', 'neutrons'];
 for(let i = 0; i < inputSelect; i++){
      document.getElementById(inputSelect[i]).setAttribute("type","select")
      const opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.textContent = "orbit";
  
      document.getElementById(inputSelect[i]).appendChild(opt)

    }
```

here is my html code

```
<label id="pro2" for = "protons2"></label>
      <input type = "text" id = "protons2" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">

      <label id="at2" for = "atomic2"></label>
      <input type = "text" id = "atomic2" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">

      <label id="new" for = "neutrons"></label>
      <input type = "text" id = "neutrons" class='input' autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer">
```

The input type does change according to the css selector input[type=text], as none of the styles of that selector is applied once the text input changes to a select input.
It still stays a text input though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please share some HTML? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: yes, i have added my text inputs into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You have to use the length value in the array to use it in the for.

2 - You can't convert an input text into a select. You have to replace the element.

```js
let inputSelect = ['protons2', 'atomic2', 'neutrons'];

for (let i = 0; i < inputSelect.length; i++) {

  select_aux = document.createElement("select");
  select_aux.id = inputSelect[i];
  document.getElementById(inputSelect[i]).replaceWith(select_aux);
  const opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.textContent = "orbit";

  document.getElementById(inputSelect[i]).appendChild(opt);

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="protons2">
<input type="text" id="atomic2">
<input type="text" id="neutrons">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type attribute that is select, instead you need to make a select element.

Note: You forgot to add .length to inputSelect in your loop.

```
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Creating a select with JS

```
document.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
</select>')
```

```js
let inputSelect=['protons2', 'atomic2', 'neutrons'];

for(let i = 0; i < inputSelect.length; i++){
      const opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.textContent = "orbit";
  
      document.getElementById(inputSelect[i]).appendChild(opt)

  }
```

```html
<select id="protons2">
</select>
<select id="atomic2">
</select>
<select id="neutrons">
</select>
```